# How i can get data from another object?

Tags: javascript, angular

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SAq4OtBV1SjcyZ5dGlfF?p=preview) 
I have two structures - ingredients and recipes

```
[{
    "id":"1",
    "name": "Cucumber"
 },
 ..
]
```

and

```
 [{
     "id":"1",
     "name": "Salad1",
     "recipein":[1, 3, 5]
  }, {
      ...
  }
 ]
```

and i want to show names of ingredients in each salad by press a button.
I filtered object to get ID of object, then i try to get a array of ingredients

```
getSalad(param:number) {
    this.saladId = this.recipe.filter(rec => {
        return rec.id.includes(param);
    })  

    this.getNameOfIngredients(this.saladId)
 }

 getNameOfIngredients(saladArray:any) {
     var ingredientsId = saladArray.map(function(num) {
     return num.recipein;
 });
```

i getting array [1,2,4] now i want to show all names of ingredients from this.ingredients with this array of id's.
 How can i do this?

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SAq4OtBV1SjcyZ5dGlfF?p=preview)

Answer (score 4):

I made updates in your plunker. I think thats what are you looking for: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FfEwVfnSzgiw5rxy6mLh?p=preview)

```
  getSalad(param:number) {

   this.saladId = this.recipe.filter(rec => +rec.id === param )[0];
    if(!this.saladId){
      this.currentSalad = "Salad not found";
      return;
    }
   this.currentSalad = this.getNameOfIngredients(this.saladId)

  }

  getNameOfIngredients(saladArray:any) {
    return this.ingredients.filter( ing => {
      return saladArray.recipein.indexOf(+ing.id) !== -1;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let _ingredients = []
this.ingredients.foreach((ingr)=>{
    if(this.ingreIDArry.indexof(ingr.id) > -1){
        _ingredients.push(ingr.name)
    }
})
return _ingredients
```

is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

if you can flatten the array, it would be very straightforward for us to do lookups.

Here is what you could do.

```js
const salads = [{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Salad1",
  "recipein": [1, 3, 5]
}];

const ingredients = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Cucumber"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Cucumber2"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Cucumber3"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Cucumber4"
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "name": "Cucumber5"
  }
];

const flattenIngredients = (() => {
  const output = {};
  ingredients.forEach((ingredient) => {
    output[ingredient.id] = ingredient;
  });
  return output;
})();

const getSalad = (saladId) => {
  const filteredSalad = salads.filter((salad) => {
    return saladId == salad.id;
  });
  if (filteredSalad.length > 0) {
    const salad = filteredSalad[0];
    return salad.recipein.map((receip) => flattenIngredients[receip].name);
  }
}

console.log(getSalad(1));
```